# Alternative trigonometries?

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

Are there alternative ones or generalizations of trigonometry?

I heard there is something similar to trigonometry but with elliptic functions...
There are also spherical, Minkowski, Riemannian trigonometries that make use of hyperbolic functions in addition to the trigonometric ones.
But are there other variants?

For instance, some kinds of discrete trigonometries, trigonometries over primes or in other discrete spaces, trigonometries on fractals, trigonometries in fractional or negative dinensions, graphs, involving information and entropy, combinatorics, or involving probabilities?
What is trigonometry in a Hilbert space?

Particularly, I am interested in examples where non-elementary functions arise instead of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: To your last question: we can define angles the usual way using an *inner product* and cosine.